# nginx how to redirect all pagination

Tags: nginx, redirect, pagination

I need help with my nginx configuration.

The goal is to have all requests to my site like `site/page1` `site/smth/page1` be redirected to just `site/` and `site/smth/` basically for all requests ending like `page[number]`

I tried some examples that I found like `rewrite ^/page/(.*)$ /$1;` still wasn't able to get the redirection. Maybe I misplaced it, not quite sure where I should put the sting. Tried location and server blocks.

The nginx documentation examples for redirecting were a bit too hard to understand for me, so a little explanation would be great.

Comment: Do you mean that `site` is your domain name?

Comment: Yes, it is my domain name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a 301 HTTP redirection, try this rewrite rule (before the first `location` block):

```
rewrite ^(.*/)page\d+$ $1 permanent;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this (not tested)

```
location ~ ^/(.+)/page[0-9]+$ {
  rewrite ^/(.+)/page[0-9]+$ /$1 last;
}
```

Comment: Tried that with fixing the typo, but still nothing ):